# plotly : I want to include some pattern in the bars of a bar chart

Tags: javascript, plotly

Language : JavaScript

I want to include some patterns in my bars of bar chart. I dont see anything available in plotly by default to serve the purpose .

So I tried getting hold of the "point" element in the dynamically generated "svg" component.And then create a "pattern" element. I thought after creating the inner pattern tag , i will able to set cusotom attributes.

But its not working at all.

Below is the code sample used :

```
var data = [{
  x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  y: [20, 14, 23],
  type: 'bar'
}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv',data);

var ticks = document.getElementsByClassName('point');
for (var i = 0; i < ticks.length; i += 1) {
          var patt = document.createElement("pattern");
          patt.setAttribute('patternTransform','rotate(30)');
          patt.setAttribute('patternUnits','userSpaceOnUse');
          patt.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
          ticks[i].appendChild(patt);

}
```

And I am taking reference of the below "" tag which I found online somewhere..

```
<pattern id="diagonal-stripes-4-8" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8"    patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(30)">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="4" height="8" style="stroke:none; fill:purple;" />
</pattern>
```

Comment: You could try using https://riccardoscalco.github.io/textures/

Comment: There is an open issue (feature) on this: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3815

Answer (score 1):

[There now is builtin pattern support](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/5520). We can now use a [`pattern`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/bar/#bar-marker-pattern) object.

The pattern has multiple options, one of them being `shape`:

> Type: enumerated or array of enumerateds , one of ( "" | "/" | "" | "x" | "-" | "|" | "+" | "." )
> Default: ""
> Sets the shape of the pattern fill. By default, no pattern is used for filling the area.

So for example you could do something like this:

```js
const data = [{
  x: ["giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"],
  y: [20, 14, 23],
  type: "bar",
  marker: {
    pattern: {
      shape: "-",
    },
  },
}, ];

Plotly.newPlot("graph", data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="graph" style="width: 1000; height: 550px"></div>
```

For some examples of pattern combinations you could look at [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/cc1c2b0d50afa2e546d47e5a6d2448447afe1457/test/image/mocks/pattern_bars.json).

Now in the case your specific pattern is not covered by the options `pattern` provides, you could target the `pattern` element and set your own custom pattern. As an example I will take the rectangle pattern example you listed in your question:

```js
const data = [{
  x: ["giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"],
  y: [20, 14, 23],
  type: "bar",
  marker: {
    pattern: {
      shape: "-",
    },
  },
}, ];

Plotly.newPlot("graph", data);

document.querySelector("pattern").innerHTML = "<rect x='0' y='0' width='4' height='8' style='stroke:none; fill:purple;' />"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="graph" style="width: 1000; height: 550px"></div>
```